Drupal Behat Selenium2 integration issue
I am integration Behat in Drupal 10 Project. I want to integrate selenium2 driver.
Installed the    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.7" getting below error when I ran the behat test.
Selenum standalone server running properly
Behat.yaml
    default:
    suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      sessions:
        first_session:
          selenium2: ~
        second_session:
          goutte: ~
        third_session:
          selenium2: ~
      base_url: 'http://bddfiserv.ddev.site/dashboard'

    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
      region_map:
        header: "#header"
        sitefooter: ".site-footer"




Scenario: Valid Login Credentials                          # features/Dashboard.feature:7
    Given I am on the homepage                               # Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext::iAmOnHomepage()
      Could not open connection: Could not start a new session. New session request timed out 
      Host info: host: 'ac653352b644', ip: '172.22.0.4'
      Build info: version: '4.9.0', revision: 'd7057100a6'
      System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.5.11-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.18'
      Driver info: driver.version: unknown (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

